# elif statement not running?

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement

The aim is to open the page get url nr 18, swap the url with url in position 18 and rerun 7 times but my code is stuck after getting position 18, why is the elif not running in line 24 ? (no traceback given, program just sitting there)

```
import urllib
from BeautifulSoup import *

#not the real url
url= ('http://abc.googl.com')
count=7
position = 0

#n will be used to check that the code i running
n=0

while count >= 0:
    html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

    tags = soup('a')
    for tag in tags:
        x= tag.get('href', None)
        position=position+1
        if position <= 18:
            n=n+1
            print 'calculating', n
            print x
        elif position == 18:
            url=(x)
            print 'new url', x
            count=count-1
            print 'new count', count
            position=0


if count == 0:
    print "done"
    print x
```

Comment: changed the value of the if, now the only problem is that it doesn't stop when reaching count 0. i'll figure it out :) Thank you everyone for the answers, very helpful!

Comment: Please don't edit in a solution into your question. Instead, you can mark *one* of the answers as 'accepted' to indicate that you found that one the most useful (and not marking an answer is also fine). See [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
if position <= 8:
```

by

```
if position < 8:
```

And leave your `elif` the same.

By having the condition `<=8` your code always enter the if (When `position` is `<=8`), but when is 9 (`>8`) it will enter the `elif`. So if you want that the code enters the `elif` statement when `position = 8`, the `if` can not be true when `position = 8`.

Comment: @Schwarz if someone gave you the right answer you should mark the response as such

Answer (score 2):

```
if position <= 18:
    ...
elif position == 18:
    ...
```

Both the `if` and `elif` branches are catching `position` if `position == 18` (note the `<=` in the `if` statement), so the `elif` branch will never be executed.

Answer (score 2):

Your `if` *excludes* the `elif` condition:

```
if position <= 18:
```

This matches if `position == 18` *too*. Python ignores all following `elif` conditions when a `if` or `elif` branch has matched.

If you want to run *additional* code for the `== 18` case, use a new `if` statement:

```
if position <= 18:
     # will run for all values of `position up to and including 18

if position == 18:
     # will *also* be run for the `position == 18` case
```

Alternatively, fix your conditions to not overlap:

```
if position < 18:
     # ...
elif position == 18:
     # runs only when position is exactly equal to 18
```

or

```
if position <= 18:
     # ...
else:
     # runs when the first condition no longer matches, so position > 18
```